# How cast parent into child to call right function in C#

Tags: c#, inheritance

I Work on c#/Code first
I've a Parent Class
`abstract public class form_base {}`
 and severals differents childs class.
Here one of them

```
 public class form_Frais : form_base    {
}
```

I've a view with all form_base, but when i click on one, I open a common template.
I just need change the mapping according to child type in changing the controler/Function by an URL

Then In my form_base
I had this :

```
 public T Cast<T>(object o)
    {
        return (T)o;
    }

    public dynamic converttt(Type LeTyp)
    {
        MethodInfo castMethod = GetType().GetMethod("Cast").MakeGenericMethod(new[] { LeTyp });
        dynamic castedObject = castMethod.Invoke(Activator.CreateInstance(LeTyp), new object[] { this });
        return castedObject;
    }
```

I've split my project in 2 part (engine/Web) My classes are define in engine

My problem is to fill my list of all form_base in web part.
I use this function in controler part

```
 public ActionResult demandeur()
    {
        object model;

            model = new {  formsList = (from f in CurrentDBContext.forms_base  select f).ToList().getCardModel(false) };
        }

        return View("demandeur", model);
    }
```

And In web I create extension methods (I won't see in engine part)
    public static partial class extensions
    {

```
    public static List<formListItem> getCardModel(this List<form_base> items, bool envalidation)
    {
        List<formListItem> model = new List<formListItem>();
        if (items != null && items.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (var item in items)
            {
                Type LeTyp = item.GetType().BaseType;
                dynamic castedObject = item.converttt(LeTyp);//Pb here not good type : System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.form_Frais_353DEAA5...' ne contient pas de définition pour 'getCardModel''

                model.Add(castedObject.getCardModel(envalidation));
            }
        }
        return model;
    }

    public static formListItem getCardModelBase(this form_base f)
    {
        formListItem model = new formListItem();
        model.id = f.id;
        model.libelle = f.title;
        model.libelleType = f.formType.title;
        model.libelleStatut = f.StatutInterneLibelle;
        model.demandeur = f.demandeur.fullName;
        model.idtype = f.formType.id;
        return model;
    }
 public static formListItem getCardModel(this form_Frais form, bool envalidation)
    {
        formListItem model = ((form_base)form).getCardModelBase();
        model.URL = "/forms/NoteFrais/InitForm"; //The good URL
        model.envalidation = envalidation;
        return model;
    }
}
```

I try to put all in extension part like that:

```
 public static T Cast<T>(object o)
    {
        return (T)o;
    }


    public static List<formListItem> getCardModel(this List<form_base> items, bool envalidation)
    {
        List<formListItem> model = new List<formListItem>();
        if (items != null && items.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (var item in items)
            {
                Type LeTyp = item.GetType().BaseType;
                MethodInfo castMethod = item.GetType().BaseType.GetMethod("Cast").MakeGenericMethod(new[] { LeTyp });
                dynamic castedObject = castMethod.Invoke(null, new object[] { item });

                model.Add(castedObject.getCardModel(envalidation));
            }
        }
        return model;
    }

    public static formListItem getCardModelBase(this form_base f)
    {
        formListItem model = new formListItem();
        model.id = f.id;
        model.libelle = f.title;
        model.libelleType = f.formType.title;
        model.libelleStatut = f.StatutInterneLibelle;
        model.demandeur = f.demandeur.fullName;
        model.idtype = f.formType.id;
        return model;
    }
```

But I've error in  item.GetType().BaseType.GetMethod("Cast").MakeGenericMethod(new[] { LeTyp }); cause GetMethod("Cast") return null

All my research come from [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/fe14d396-bc35-4f98-851d-ce3c8663cd79/dynamic-casting-in-c-at-runtime?forum=csharplanguage)

### UPDATE

In resume, In first try, I've problem of type class return dynamicproxy...
And in static version, I can't find method Cast..

I try

```
 MethodInfo[] methodInfos = LeTyp.GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static);
```

But My array is empty... then my problem in static version will be hwo save correctly my Case function??? and use it in extension method

### UPDATE 3

I find the problem in static mode
I need tu put Cast function in note_frais class
and use it

```
 Type LeTyp = item.GetType().BaseType;
                //MethodInfo[] methodInfos = LeTyp.GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static);
                MethodInfo MI = LeTyp.GetMethod("Cast");//<T>.getMethod(cast)
                MI = MI.MakeGenericMethod(typeof(form_base));
                dynamic t = MI.Invoke(null, new object[] { item });

                model.Add(t.getCardModel(envalidation));
```

But now I've same pb in 2 parts :

> //Pb here not good type : System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.form_Frais_353DEAA5...' ne contient pas de définition pour 'getCardModel''

Thanks for your help? I read lot of things but now I'm completly lost.

Comment: It's a little difficult to decipher the code, and know what is defined where, it would be much better if you posted the full classes in uninterrupted code blocks, better yet would be to post a minimal example that illustrates the problem.

Comment: I do it in the day. Sorry for my late. I'm very busy...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally... With a simple sample it's good

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Reflection;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
  abstract public class form_base
  {
    public Guid Guid { get; set; }

}
public class form_Frais : form_base
{
    public int MonInt { get; set; }

    public static T Cast<T>(object o)
    {
        return (T)o;
    }
}
public class form_Avoir : form_base
{
    public int MonInt { get; set; }

    public static T Cast<T>(object o)
    {
        return (T)o;
    }
}

public static class extensions
{
    public static int GetCardModel(this form_Avoir form)
    {
        return form.MonInt * 100;
    }

    public static int GetCardModel(this form_Frais form)
    {
        return form.MonInt * form.MonInt;
    }
}

public class TOTO
{
    public static int GetCardModel(form_Avoir form)
    {
        return form.MonInt * 100;
    }

    public static int GetCardModel(form_Frais form)
    {
        return form.MonInt * form.MonInt;
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
        form_Frais nf = new form_Frais();
        nf.Guid = Guid.NewGuid();
        nf.MonInt = 2;
        List<form_base> lst = new List<form_base>();
        //MethodInfo[] methodInfos = typeof(form_base).GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static);
        lst.Add(nf);
        form_Avoir av = new form_Avoir();
        av.Guid = Guid.NewGuid();
        av.MonInt = 5;
        lst.Add(av);

        foreach (dynamic f in lst)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(TOTO.GetCardModel(f)); // OK
            //Type LeTyp = f.GetType();
            //MethodInfo MI = LeTyp.GetMethod("Cast");//<T>.getMethod(cast)
            //MI = MI.MakeGenericMethod(typeof(form_base));
            //dynamic t = MI.Invoke(null, new object[] { f });
            //Console.WriteLine(t.GetCardModel());// Error 
        }
    }
  }
}
```

My error was to thought that extension methods was include in object. In fact not. It seems but not really. I just change with a method with parameter instead of extension

Answer (score 2):

Instead of:

`GetMethod("Cast")`

...try this overload:

`GetMethod("Cast", new Type[] { typeof(Object) })`

**More observations...**

The `Cast<T>` method of class `form_base` is **not** static. (See above to get this one.)

The class `form_base` doesn't define **any** public static methods.

(Side note, I'm not sure why the class `extensions` is defined as `partial`.)

The `Cast<T>` method in class `extensions` **is** static, but is **not** an extension method.

To get this one, you can use this overload, ***on type `extensions`***:

```
typeof(extensions).GetMethod("Cast", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static, null, new Type[] { typeof(Object) }, null)
```

If you did define the `Cast<T>` *extension* method in class `extensions`:

```
public static partial class extensions {
    public static T Cast<T>(this form_base b, object o) {/*…*/}
}
```

...then you could get it with the same overload ***on type `extensions`***, by modifying the `types` argument:

```
typeof(extensions).GetMethod("Cast", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static, null, new Type[] { typeof(form_base), typeof(Object) }, null)
```